# Can I use atomics in an asynchronous context?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, mutex, atomic, rwlock

Is there a way to use atomic types in an asynchronous context instead of an asynchronous `Mutex` or `RwLock`? Can standard atomics be used as is in an asynchronous context?

Or, for example, is there an asynchronous equivalent of `std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize` with `load` / `store` methods, which could replace something like `tokio::sync::RwLock<usize>` with `read().await` / `write().await` methods?

Comment: Why would `load` or `store` be asynchronous? They operate immediately.

Comment: Yes, Atomics are perfectly fine for async usage. Generally you shouldn't even be using the async `Mutex` and `RwLock`s unless you have to hold a lock across an await point.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was searching for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using Atomics in an async context is no problem.

Most of them are lock-free (=can't even block).

Even if you would block, it is still recommended to use normal, blocking synchronization primitives over async ones, unless you hold that lock during an `await`.

For more info I quote the [respective chapter of the tokio tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state):

> **On using `std::sync::Mutex`**
>
> Note, `std::sync::Mutex` and **not** `tokio::sync::Mutex` is used to guard the `HashMap`. A common error is to unconditionally use `tokio::sync::Mutex` from within async code. An async mutex is a mutex that is locked across calls to `.await`.
>
> A synchronous mutex will block the current thread when waiting to acquire the lock. This, in turn, will block other tasks from processing. However, switching to `tokio::sync::Mutex` usually does not help as the asynchronous mutex uses a synchronous mutex internally.
>
> As a rule of thumb, using a synchronous mutex from within asynchronous code is fine as long as contention remains low and the lock is not held across calls to `.await`. Additionally, consider using [`parking_lot::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/0.10.2/parking_lot/type.Mutex.html) as a faster alternative to `std::sync::Mutex`.

Note that this is of course only true if all the threads accessing said lock/atomic are also async worker threads. If you have external threads that could block the mutex, you have to consider waiting for that mutex a blocking operation and treat it as such.

Comment: Atomics in Rust never block (unlike e.g. C++).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Meanin, they simply won't compile in architectures that don't support them?

Comment: Yes. They are not available there. `#[cfg(target_has_atomic = "size")]` can be used to conditionally compile based on that.